# How to set and get values from an url

Tags: php

I would like to set values on an url like this:

```
<a href='http://$data_url/viewyournote.php?chapter='$name_of_chapter'&note='$id_note'&user='$username'>
```

Then be able to grab then from the recieving page.

Right now all im getting is this when clicked:

```
http://localhost/readnotes/viewyournote.php?chapter=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't how you embed your link in your code, but if it is outside of `<?php ?>` tags, then you have to do:

```
<a href="http://<?php echo $data_url ?>/viewyournote.php?chapter=<?php echo $name_of_chapter ?>&note=<?php echo $id_note ?>&user=<?php echo $username?>" >
```

if it is inside these tags, you can also do:

```
echo  "<a href='http://$data_url/viewyournote.php?chapter=$name_of_chapter&note=$id_note&user=$username?' >";
```

You can get these values on the recieveing page with `$_GET['variable_name_here']`, e.g. `$_GET['chapter']`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Query string

$val = "yourvalue" ;

$url "http://localhost/readnotes/viewyournote.php?chapter=$val";

Now $val is passed to specified url .

There you could get it by using $_GET['chapter'] , It will give you "yourvalue"

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href='http://$data_url/viewyournote.php?chapter=<?php echo $name_of_chapter; ?>&note=<?php echo $id_note; ?>&user=<?php echo $username; ?>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line with

```
<?php
echo "<a href='http://$data_url/viewyournote.php?chapter='$name_of_chapter'&note='$id_note' user='$username'>";
 ?>
```

On the receiving end use

```
<?php
$name_of_chapter = $_GET['chapter'];
...
?>
```